# Velocity potential in conical coordinate

Tags: potential-theory

[Velocity potential in conical coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTTK6.png)
I just want to make sure that the equation regarding velocity potential in conical coordinates (the above picture) is correct or if there is a typo. I came across this equation in an ISI paper and have been trying to verify it by searching through various books and online sources. Unfortunately, I have only found velocity potential equations for Cartesian, cylindrical, and spherical coordinates, but not for conical coordinates. The only relation that I have found in all the references is the following equation; however, I am unsure how to determine the values of a, b, and c in order to obtain the equation mentioned above. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me with this.
[general conical coordinate equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MilMV.png)